# How to count the number of questions that have the average score below 3.0

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here is the table example. The decimal values are the averages. On the left are the course titles in one column. Across the matrix are the questions as string. The values are the averages which I'm trying to check which question has the value below 3.0 and count the number of questions which has the average value below 3.0 and show in one column.

In the screen shot below the question 2 for course 3 has average below 3.0 and also for course 2 the question 4 has value below 3.0 and I would like to count those questions and display in one column. Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also tried this but it only shows 1's in the last column instead of counting or summing all those question averages below 3.0. Any ideas on this? Test Measure  = if([Question 1 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 + if([Question 2 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 + if( [Question 3 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if( [Question 4 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +   if([Question 5 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +   if([Question 6 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +   if([Question 7 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if( [Question 8 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +   if([Question 9 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if([Question 10 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if( [Question 11 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if( [Question 12 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +   if([Question 13 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if( [Question 14 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +   if([Question 15 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if( [Question 16 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if([Question 17 Measure] < 3, 1, 0 +  if([Question 18 Measure] < 3, 1 , 0 +  if( [Question 19 Measure] < 3, 1 ,0)))))))))))))))))))

Comment: I edited my post above. I tried that but as you can see it's counting them all wrong. It should only count those question with less than 3 but it's counting everything as seen in the last column. Also the count for less than 3 are all wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this measure instead:

```
Number of Questions With Average < 3 = 
    SUMX(SUMMARIZE(
        'Table','Table'[Question],"Average Score",[Overall Average]), 
            IF([Overall Average] < 3,1,0))
```

This measure creates a virtual table called Average Score, grouping the Overall Average by Question. Then it assigns a 1 to any group(question) that has an Overall Average less than 3 and a 0 otherwise. Then it sums it up.

Here are my results with some sample data:
[image]

If you don't like the '0's, try this:

```
Number of Questions With Average < 3 = 
var result = SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[Question],"Average Score", 
                   [Overall Average]), IF([Overall Average] < 3,1,0))
return IF(result, result)
```

This will only return a result if the result is not 0.

Comment: You're genius. That worked perfectly. I do really appreciate your help. Where do I accept this solution?

Comment: I'm sorry I accepted it too fast. Some of the counts are wrong and I don't know why. In the sum I see 10 for example but when I look across the row there are 9 questions with less then 3.0. Not sure why it's calculation them wrong?

Comment: Could you share that example?

Comment: @ -user15697117. That was an issue on my side in the source data but your code worked so perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of questions with an average score < 3 as follows:

```
Number of Questions With Scores < 3 = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Question]), FILTER('Table', [Average Score] < 3))
```

However, you cannot add this as a separate column at the end of a matrix. If you have Average Score as the values in a matrix with Questions as the column headers and Courses as the rows, and you add this new measure to the values, you will get a column with this new measure for each question, and a total at the end:
[image: Matrix view]

To achieve the visual you are looking for, you would need individual average measures for each question; this would be very tedious if you have a lot of questions:

```
Question 1 Average Score = CALCULATE([Average Score], FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Question] = "Question 1"))
```

You will need to add this measure for each question by right clicking on the table you wish to add the measure to and selecting New measure:

[image: New Measure]

Then, you could include each of the Question # Average Score measures and the Number of Questions with Scores < 3 as the values and get something like this:

[image: Matrix Fields]
[image: Updated Matrix]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. I'm trying to achieve the 2nd matrix but it's not working. Where do you add all those measures for every question in the matrix? And how do you user this in the 2nd matrix? Number of Questions With Scores < 3 = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Question]), FILTER('Table', [Average Score] < 3))?

Comment: @POWERBI_SQL I have edited the example above to answer your questions. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I did that exactly but it kept repeating. What goes in the Columns section?

Comment: @POWERBI_SQL nothing should go in the Columns section if you are creating a separate measure for each question. Make sure to update each measure to reference the correct question. In the example above, we filter the table for only questions that = "Question 1" (this should be changed to the actual question text in your data); the measure for question 2 needs to be updated to filter the table for questions that = "Question 2" and so on.

Comment: @ user15697117. I did that exactly and referenced all those questions. For example like this  Question 1 Measure = CALCULATE([Average Score], FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Question] = "What is your overall experience")). But I get weird count at the end. It also counts those with average above 3.0. Still all the counts are wrong

Comment: @POWERBI_SQL The measures for each question will still count scores above 3.0, unless you add add another filter. The Number of Questions with Scores < 3 measure should only count those questions with scores less than 3.0.
Can you share your measures and results?

Comment: I have shared the measures and results in the screen shot above.

Comment: What filter I should add?

Comment: I'm really running out of time. Can you please help?

Comment: Can you share the DAX for the measure Number of Questions With Average Score < 3?
It should be something like:
= Calculate(Count(Table[Question]), Filter(Table, Average(Table[Score]) < 3))

Comment: Here.  

 

Number of Questions With Average score < 3 = CALCULATE(COUNT(‘Table’[Question]), FILTER('Table', [Overall Average Score] < 3))

Comment: But I'm looking to count the number of questions which have average score below 3.0 and show at the end as total. For example if 5 questions out of 10 questions have Average score below 3.0 then in the total column at the end it should show 5.

Comment: I added a new screen shot in my original post. As you can see it's showing 336 instead of 5 as there are 5 questions with the average score below 3.0. Any ideas?

Comment: It's also counting those with average above 3.0. Not sure why?

Comment: And can I assume your measure [Overall Average Score] = AVERAGE(Table[Score])?
The solution works with some sample data, but there may be some nuances in your dataset that I am not accounting for. Any way you can share a sample dataset?

Comment: I using this measure and excluding the count of zeros for calculating the Overall Average Score.   

 

Overall Average Score = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(‘Table’[Score]), FILTER(‘Table’, ‘Table’[Score] <>0))

Comment: I'm sorry I can't share the data set.

Comment: Anybody here to solve this?

Comment: I edited the original post. Please see above?

Comment: @ user15697117... Never mind. There was something wrong with the Question measure which I fixed and now I get the accurate result. I'm still trying to validate. But that was an amazing solution. Thank you so much